# ¿Usar funciones es más eficiente que ciclos?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.9

tengo un código en python en el que utilizo un menú, el símil al código utilizado es el siguiente:

```
def Menu():
Limpiar()
menu = int (input ("Menú\n1)Opcion 1\n2)Opcion 2\n3)Opcion 3"))
if menu == 1 :
    Opcion1()
elif menu == 2 :
    Opcion2()
elif menu == 3 :
    Opcion3()
else :
    Incorrecto()
```

Mi intención es que en lugar de usar ciclos con While, se navegue llamando funciones, ejemplo con la opcion 2:

```
def Opcion2():       
print ("Esta es la opcion numero 2")
Menu()
```

Esta función vuelve a llamar a Menu(), permitiendo la navegación sin utilizar ciclos.
La duda correspondería respecto a la eficiencia de recursos y efectividad al programar de esta manera. Considerando que soy estudiante y sabiendo que en adelante las programaciones se complejizan, ¿q tan eficiente es esta metodología en cuanto a recursos del equipo? y ¿es efectivo trabajar de esta forma o es mejor pensarlo con ciclos por alguna razón?

Comment: Lo que estás proponiendo es hacer llamadas recursivas a `Menu()`. Eso funciona, pero el stack de llamadas crecerá sin parar durante la ejecución del programa, consumiendo recursos innecesariamente.

Comment: Tal como lo planteas, si el usuario elige por ejemplo la opción 2, invocas `Opcion2()` pero esa función **nunca retorna**, porque para volver a `Menu()` hace otra llamada en lugar de un `return`. Cada llamada utiliza un trozo de la pila, y cada return libera ese trozo. Con tu enfoque nunca se liberan, y los trozos usados se van acumulando. Si el programa está en uso el tiempo suficiente y el usuario ha pasado por el menú principal muchas veces (unas 500), puedes incluso alcanzar el límite de llamadas anidadas (sin return) permitidas por python y obtener un error en tiempo de ejecución.

Comment: Leyendo los comentarios, podemos llegar a la conclusión de que hay que hacer lo posible por usar bucles en lugar de funciones recursivas. También un bucle es más legible y claro que una función recursiva.